# Scroll view on xamarin.ios not working using storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am a new with xamarin.ios, i have added a view controller on the storyboard, then added a scroll view and added also a view and put on this view some labels, but i can't scroll, what's the problem?

Comment: you set constraints to this scroll view?

Comment: I drag and drop this scroll view manually without coding.

Comment: @IonCojucovschi how to set constraints to make the height and the width of the scroll view to be higher?

Comment: So usually and do the majority, to solve your problem, install Xcode to your Mac, and open your Storyboard with XCode, its lock same as  Visual studio but with more possibilities, there you can set constraints like in native pages.

Comment: you can set this in same way like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw-wwGLbPn0

Comment: Thanks, but i work with xamarin.ios not with swift or objective c, they are different.

Comment: you can open storyboard with xcode and there set your constraints ,,, I'm also working with xamarin IOS